# Cognito User Pool with Federated Identites - how to find linked user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a Cognito Federated Identity with Cognito User Pool as Auth provider. It all works and I can see that any new user added in user pool creates a new federated identity. But how do I know which Federated Identity is linked to which user in the User Pool in my code - say a Lambda? When I browse the Identity pool in AWS console, it just shows the User pool id in linked logins and not the User pool sub. Do I need to store a mapping between User Pool's sub to Identity pool's Identity id ?

Comment: me too am looking for this answer. You have any findings?

Answer (score -1):

You can extract it from the request. e.g. For lambda extract it from the field `event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider` in the context parameter.

See these resources for how to do it.
 - https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/mapping-cognito-identity-id-and-user-pool-id.html
 - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/390

Comment: It is best to include the relevant explanations in your answer, as links may change their content or become dead in the future.